# Is there an efficient way to create an onPress event handler in React Native's Stateless/Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a **stateless/functional component** which gets an **array of objects** having two properties i.e. **title** and **onPress()** as props.

Now for the **Button** component's onPress event I want to call this **object's onPress function** as well as an **action creator** (which too is being passed as props to this component).

Is there any way to just create **one instance of onPress event handler** which would call these two functions(button object's onPress function and action creator) ?

Below is a snippet code:

```
buttons.map(button =>
  <Button
    title={button.title}
    onPress={ // call button.onPress and action creator using event handler }
  />
)
```

The reason for asking this is because every time this component would re-render the event handler too would be created again which could cause performance issue.

Comment: Could you please specify what do you pass into `<Button />`'s  "onPress" prop ?

Comment: That's what my question is. What event handler should I pass in the onPress prop of **<Button />** such that this event handler would only be created once even if the component re-renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not separate props, just pass the button itself alongside with action creator:

```
buttons.map(button =>
  <Button
      button={button}
      action={action}
  />
)
```

And in your Button component create a handlePress function and invoke the press there.

```
const Button = ( {button, action }) => { 
  const handlePress = () => {
    button.onPress();
    action();
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onPress={handlePress}>{button.title}</button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

I don't know React Native but I assume there is no so much difference with React itself.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think this whole component would be re-rendered if the parent component using it gets re-rendered which means that the handlePress event handler would be created again as well.

Comment: Component itself will be re-rendered obviously but handlePress function won't recreated. Since you are not invoking nor binding it, just using its reference. At least this what I've learned so far and I hope I am not mistaken.